# Converting pandas columns to PostgreSQL list?

Tags: python, postgresql, pandas

I'm working with a CSV of a few hundred columns, many of them are just enumerations, ie:

```
[
['code_1', 'code_2', 'code_3', ..., 'code_50'],
[1, 2, 3, ..., 50],
[2, 3, 4, ..., 51],
...
[400000, 400001, 400002, ..., 400049]
]
```

I'm importing this data into PostgreSQL and would like to concatenate these columns into an array such as:

```
[
['codes'],
['{1, 2, 3, ..., 50}']
]
```

and so on.

I'm aware of 'round-about' ways I can accomplish this such as

```
df['codes'] = pd.DataFrame(["{" + df['code_1'] + ", " + df['code_2'] + "}"]).T
```

but that's **a lot** of redundant code to write and maintain given the size of this CSV.

What I basically have to work with is a column list, I've already extracted the enumerated columns such as:

```
codes = [
    'code_1',
    'code_2',
    'code_3',
    ...
]
```

Before I begin writing my own custom "`implode_columns(arr)`" function, is there anything in pandas that already solves this problem or has special ways of accommodating PostgreSQL arrays in convenient ways?

Comment: I used to work with python, csv, and postgres, but not pandas. I know a bit about this. What is the source .csv field? And what fields that exist in postgres table? Why not use for in for to insert every field? But it depends on your RAM.

Comment: @colintobing Here's the source fields http://pastebin.com/eXxxTtwN I'm starting with taxonomies because it's flat, healthcare_provider_taxonomy_codes and other_provider_identifiers will be nested, but by then I'll have a better angle to approach them from.  I was using pandas to avoid having to deal with 300 columns individually, but if I can reduce this down to a more logical table then creating a model won't be too much work. Memory won't be an issue. Perhaps I am creating more work for myself by using pandas, this CSV is just such an awful mess.

Answer (score 0):

Assumed that you already connect to PostgreSQL and already have the table in PostgreSQL. Or visit this link https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Psycopg2_Tutorial

```
import psycopg2

try:
    conn = psycopg2.connect("host='localhost' dbname='template1' user='dbuser' password='dbpass'")
except:
    print "I am unable to connect to the database"
```

First, open the .csv file.

```
>>> import csv
>>> with open('names.csv') as csvfile:
...     reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
...     for row in reader:
...         print(row['first_name'], row['last_name'])
...
```

That's example from https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html
Change the print line with insert into PostgreSQL.

```
>>> import psycopg2    
>>> cur.execute("INSERT INTO test (num, data) VALUES (%s, %s)",
    ...      (100, "abc'def"))
```

You can change (100, "abc'def") with (variable1, variable2) See this link http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html
Or in full sample code:

```
>>> import csv
>>> import psycopg2
>>> with open('names.csv') as csvfile:
...     reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
...     for row in reader:
...         cur.execute("INSERT INTO test (num, data) VALUES (%s, %s)", (variable1, variable2))
...
```

Hope this will help...